# Convert String to Datetime or Datetime 2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need help because I can't convert it by myself. I got the following String:

```
20160803093000000
```

Inside the String there is the Date and Time: 2016-08-03 09:30:00:00

I need it as Datetime or Datetime2.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Pro-Tip Google for *t-sql yyyymmddhhmmss to datetime*

Comment: I tried a lot of things. Da Source is of the datatype bigint. Iam not working so long with SQL so i would be glad if someone could help me.

Comment: If iam trying this here: SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@t,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':')) i get the Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is with the milliseconds (I entered another date, so you can see the change in the milliseconds):

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(50)
SET @t = '20160803093012345'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@t,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':'),18,0,'.'))
```

I read something about loss of precision at the millisecond level, though. So there is still some need for research on the topic.

If you need the precision of the milliseconds, you can use DATETIME2 and just do:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@t,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':'),18,0,'.'))
```

I just read a great article regarding the precision. It says:

> If you want to store the exact same value you had in DATETIME, just
>   choose DATETIME2(3), you get the same precision but it only takes 7
>   bytes to store the value instead of 8.

Here is the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/) for more information.

Comment: @AlexK. You are right. I edited my answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@t,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':'),18,0,'.'))

Works fine! Thank you a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help. Can you please mark my answer above as the correct answer if you think that is the case? Thanks. :)

Comment: To mark the answer as accepted, just click on the check mark next to my answer to turn it green. Here is a how-to link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work